# Vue.js - prop binded to component not showing the right result

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this SwitchButton component in my Vue.js app that has a custom event 'toggle'. When clicking (switching) the button, the toggle event sets isEnabled to false or true. No problems with that but when I bind isEnabled in the parent component to the SwitchButton child component to set its initial value, it doesn't seem to work.

Code used in parent component (giving isEnabled true as initial value)

```
<SwitchButton v-model="distSwitch" :isEnabled="true">
    <label slot="left">{{ $t('general.dealer') }}</label>
    <label slot="right">{{ $t('general.wholesale') }}</label>
</SwitchButton>
```

SwitchButton component:

```
<template>
    <div class="switch-button-control">
        <div class="switch-button-label">
            <slot name="left"></slot>
        </div>
        <div class="switch-button" :class="{'enabled': isEnabled}" @click="toggle">
            <div class="button"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="switch-button-label">
            <slot name="right"></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'SwitchButton',
    model: {
        prop: 'isEnabled',
        event: 'toggle'
    },
    props: {
        isEnabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle() {
            this.$emit("toggle", !this.isEnabled);
        }
    },
    created() {
        /*eslint-disable no-console*/
        console.log('isEnabled', this.isEnabled)
    }
}
</script>
```

**I expect the console.log in the created hook to output "isEnabled > true" but it outputs "false" instead**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value for the property `isEnabled` is set by a hard codded `true`, changing it from the child component won't work.

Initialising a data variable in parent component and set as property can help here.

Template:

```
<SwitchButton v-model="distSwitch" :isEnabled="isEnabled" @toggle="toggleIsEnabled">
    <label slot="left">{{ $t('general.dealer') }}</label>
    <label slot="right">{{ $t('general.wholesale') }}</label>
</SwitchButton>
```

Data:

```
data:()=>{
  return {
    isEnabled:true
  }
}
```

Create a method in the `methods` section:

```
toggleIsEnabled:function(value){
   this.isEnabled = value;
}
```

The emitted value from `SwitchButton` component using the custom event emitter `toggle` will trigger the callback function `toggleIsEnabled` in the parent component.